# Nexus kills forwarding from apache to tomcat

Tags: ssl, apache2, tomcat6, war, nexus

I'm trying to run Nexus as a war in tomcat6. It deploys, starts and initializes and doesn't show any errors in the logs but it kills forwarding from apache to tomcat.

We are using `libapache2-mod-jk` and this should be correctly configured. Hudson is also running as a war and also doesn't work anymore. If I remove nexus from tomcat everything works fine again.

The error I found was in `/var/log/apache2/mod_jk.log`:

```
[error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1630): (ajp13_worker) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=111)
```

Config looks like this `/etc/libapache2-mod-jk/workers.properties`

```
#------ worker list ------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#
# The workers that your plugins should create and work with
# 
worker.list=ajp13_worker

#
#------ ajp13_worker WORKER DEFINITION ------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
#

#
# Defining a worker named ajp13_worker and of type ajp13
# Note that the name and the type do not have to match.
#
worker.ajp13_worker.port=8009
worker.ajp13_worker.host=localhost
worker.ajp13_worker.type=ajp13
#
# Specifies the load balance factor when used with
# a load balancing worker.
# Note:
#  ----> lbfactor must be > 0
#  ----> Low lbfactor means less work done by the worker.
worker.ajp13_worker.lbfactor=1

#
# Specify the size of the open connection cache.
#worker.ajp13_worker.cachesize

#
#------ DEFAULT LOAD BALANCER WORKER DEFINITION ----------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
#

#
# The loadbalancer (type lb) workers perform wighted round-robin
# load balancing with sticky sessions.
# Note:
#  ----> If a worker dies, the load balancer will check its state
#        once in a while. Until then all work is redirected to peer
#        workers.
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=ajp13_worker
```

And in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl`

```
######## Tomcat

JkMount /agilefant/* ajp13_worker
JkMount /hudson/* ajp13_worker
JKMount /nexus/* ajp13_worker
```

Any idea?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not run Nexus as a war. This is not recommended and about to be completely deprecated. Run it from the bundle download that has a preconfigure Eclipse Jetty instance in it.

Comment: I was hoping that the war would have been enough for our requirements

Comment: The load of running it as a separate servlet container is minimal and it isolates it nicely from other services. E.g. if Tomcat/Hudson goes crashes out, Nexus can still hum along and the other way around.